# Advice regarding SQL injection protection using a prepared statement (for use with Node-Red)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, node-red

Background: I'm using Node-Red to accept potentially untrusted input and subsequently place that data in a Microsoft SQL Server database table. Whilst my environment is internal only, I would still like to protect against an internal malicious actor attempting to do silly things. Node-Red `MSSQL` modules do not protect against SQL injection at all, and I don't trust myself to adequately perform sanitation / catch edge cases.

I have seen some advice that using prepared statements with MySQL will go a long way to alleviating SQL Injection attacks, meaning that a variable set to `'; DROP mytable;` will not in fact drop mytable but rather treat that potential statement as a string. I have, however, been able to find very little readable / understandable information on using prepared statements with SQL Server.

That said, I was able to use the example insert statement below, so assume the advice may well be the same.

So the question is: can I use something like the following to alleviate the risk of SQL injection with Microsoft SQL Server?

```
INSERT INTO [DBName].[dbo].[User_Details] 
   (First_Name, 
    Last_Name, 
    Primary_Phone, 
    Secondary_Phone, 
    Email,
    Organisation, 
    Home_Region, 
    Role) 
VALUES ('Potato',
        'Head',
        '0444444444',
        '0411111111',
        'potato.head@myorganisation.com',
        'My Organisation',
        'State Office',
        'Chief Ape')
```

If I cannot, are there other suggestions? There is no ORM available so far as I can tell, and I'm wary of regex sanitising etc as my ability to cover edge cases is probably not great.

Comment: I can't speak to Node-RED but prepared statements/parameterized queries do protect against SQL injection. However, the query must have parameter markers instead of literals and the parameters/values added to the prepared statement object.

Comment: Dan, thanks. I'm not sure how to interpret the second half of your advice there - I'm not so intimately familiar with SQL. Would you mind elaborating a little, or providing an example of how that might be achieved? Thanks. For the purpose of this exercise I'm executing raw SQL via node-red, basically the same as if I was in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: The `VALUES` clause of a parameterized insert would be like `VALUES(?, ? ? ...` instead of `VALUES ('Potato', 'Head', '0444444444'...`. The parameter markers may differ depending on the driver/API. Some support named parameter like `VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @Phone...`.

Comment: FWIW, I found [this library](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-mssql-ps) with an internet search.

Comment: I've managed to miss that on every search, thanks. I'll have to see how it goes.

Comment: The idea is that you use placeholders for the data. SQL Server will never interpret these placeholders as code. Note that you do not need quotes `''` around the placeholders